# Pointplacement for a column when two columns are shown in same chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am showing two series as columns in a chart . The first serie representing a day value and the second series representing the hour values. I want to make the day series to start at 6am the same day and end next day at 6am. This is working ok with pointplacement=0.5. But only when the series is showed alone. When it is showed together with the hour series, the pointplacement is not longer working. How can this be done correctly ?
https://jsfiddle.net/Kjellis/esg0hur7/60/

```
Highcharts.chart('container',{
       chart: {
           zoomType: 'x',
           events: {
            load: function () {  
                if(this.series.length >1 ){

                 if(this.xAxis[0].series[0].points.length>1){                         this.series[0].options.pointPlacement = 0.5;
                    var t=this.xAxis[0].series[0].points[1].plotX - this.xAxis[0].series[0].points[0].plotX 
                    this.series[0].options.pointWidth=t;
                 }


                  this.series[0].options.pointPlacement = 0.5;
                  this.series[0].update(this.series[0].options);
                  this.series[1].update(this.series[1].options);
                }
            },
            },


        },   

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts columns'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    second: '%d-%m-%Y<br/>%H:%M:%S',
                    minute: '%d-%m-%Y<br/>%H:%M',
                    hour: '%d-%m-%Y<br/>%H:%M',
                    day: '%d-%m<br/>%Y',
                    week: '%d-%m<br/>%Y',
                    month: '%Y-%m',
                    year: '%Y'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    color: 'black', 
                    width: 2,
                    value: Date.now() 
                }]
            },

        series:[
        {
            type: 'column',
          data:[
          [1557813600000,12.6],
          [1557900000000,30],
          [1557986400000,10]]
        },
        {
            type: 'column',
          data:[
          [1557813600000, 1],
          [1557817200000, 2],
          [1557820800000, 0],
          [1557824400000, 3],
          [1557828000000, 4],
          [1557831600000, 5],
          [1557835200000, 6],
          [1557838800000, 7],
          [1557842400000, 0],
          [1557846000000, 1],
          [1557849600000, 2],
          [1557853200000, 3],
          [1557856800000, 5],
          [1557860400000, 6],
          [1557864000000, 7],
          [1557867600000, 0],
          [1557871200000, 0],
          [1557874800000, 0],
          [1557878400000, 1],
          [1557882000000, 2],
          [1557885600000, 0],
          [1557889200000, 0],
          [1557892800000, 0],
          [1557896400000, 3],
          [1557900000000, 3],
          [1557903600000, 4],
          [1557907200000, 6],
          [1557910800000, 0],
          [1557914400000, 1],
          [1557918000000, 10],
          [1557921600000, 1],
          [1557925200000, 0],
          [1557928800000, 30],
          [1557932400000, 4],
          [1557936000000, 3],
          [1557939600000, 0],
          [1557943200000, 3],
          [1557946800000, 0],
          [1557950400000, 2],
          [1557954000000, 0],
          [1557957600000, 0],
          [1557961200000, 5],
          [1557964800000, 7],
          [1557968400000, 5],
          [1557972000000, 3],
          [1557975600000, 0],
          [1557979200000, 0],
          [1557982800000, 3],
          [1557986400000, 0],
          [1557990000000, 0],
          [1557993600000, 0],
          [1557997200000, 7],
          [1558000800000, 6],
          [1558004400000, 2],
          [1558008000000, 3],
          [1558011600000, 5],
          [1558015200000, 5],
          [1558018800000, 10],
          [1558022400000, 4],
          [1558026000000, 7],
          [1558029600000, 0],
          [1558033200000, 0],
          [1558036800000, 6],
          [1558040400000, 5],
          [1558044000000, 4],
          [1558047600000, 3],
          [1558051200000, 1],
          [1558054800000, 1],
          [1558058400000, 10],
          [1558062000000, 0]
          ]
          }]});
```

Comment: Hi @Kjell Ivar Sangro, Could you describe in more detail or create some visialization how the chart should look like?

Comment: Hi, in the fiddler example attached it is visible if you turn on or off the serie for hours (serie2) . If the serie2 is shown the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `grouping` and set the right `pointRange`:

```
series: [{
        type: 'column',
        pointRange: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day
        grouping: false,
        data: [...]
    },
    {
        type: 'column',
        pointRange: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1 hour
        grouping: false,
        data: [...]
    }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/esjmLb2t/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the answer . It works like i wanted !
 
But an additional question is how can i get the xAxis to show the hours columns with higher resolution ? So when i zoom in the hours can be shown on the xaxis.

Comment: Hi @Kjell Ivar Sangro, You can use `afterSetExtremes` event and `show/hide` methods on the series. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v9qaxn34/

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your answer, but it was not quite what i meant. I just want to have the hours value to be shown at the x-axis. Now there is a lot of space between whole dates for example between 14-05-2019 and 15-05-2019. Can I have more hours on the x axis when zooming in like
 14-05-2019 01:00   14-05-2019 03:00   14-05-2019 05:00 14-05-2019 07:00 and so on….

Comment: @Kjell Ivar Sangro, Ok, so setting `tickInterval` should be enough. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lnhzfmo7/